# Getting ALAsset object from camera

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, alasset, elcimagepickercontroller

How can  I get  ALAsset object in - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 after making photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  An ALAsset is a representation of an entry in the photo albums somewhere. You only get them when you add the assetsLibrary framework (obviously) and enumerate the albums.

The camera doesn't create an ALAsset, they're only representations of media in photo albums